# Obtain concordance correlation coefficient accounting for errors in data

Tags: measurement, agreement-statistics

I have two 1-dimensional data sets that measure the same process by two different methods:

$$x=[x_1, x_2, ..., x_N]\; ;\; y=[y_1, y_2, ..., y_N]$$

I need to asses the agreement between these two methods, where ideally I'd have:

$$x_1=y_1, x_2=y_2, ..., x_N=y_N$$

meaning a perfect agreement. After some research I decided to use the [Concordance Correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concordance_correlation_coefficient) ($r_c$). I'm following the recipe given in [Assessing agreement of measurements and predictions in geomorphology, Cox N.J. (2006)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0169555X05003740) to obtain it as:

$$r_c=\frac{2s_{xy}}{s_x^2 + s_y^2 + (\bar{x} - \bar{y})^2}$$

where $\bar{x}, \bar{y}$ are the means, $s_x^2, s_y^2$ are the variances and $s_{xy}$ is the covariance between the two data sets. This works perfectly, but my two data sets actually have uncertainties for each measured value. This is:

$$\sigma_x=[\sigma_{x_1}, \sigma_{x_2}, ..., \sigma_{x_N}]\;;\;\sigma_y=[\sigma_{y_1}, \sigma_{y_2}, ..., \sigma_{y_N}]$$

Is there a way to incorporate these uncertainties into the $r_c$ coefficient?

Comment: My guess is that concordance correlation is a dead end for you. You need to work with a model directly. The situation is analogous to the Pearson or Spearman correlations, which in the first instance are just defined as descriptive statistics and don't have different flavours for different models of generating process.

Comment: Thanks @NickCox (and great article BTW!) Any suggestions as to where I need to look at? I'm not a statistician so my knowledge is rather limited.

Comment: Everyone seems to say structural equation models here, but in turn that is unexplored territory for me. (Thanks for the BTW!)

Comment: O_O that sounds a bit out of my league. I'll check it out nevertheless. Would you mind posting an answer saying that it can't be done so I can close the question?

Comment: Thanks (again) for the compliment, but I don't want to elevate my guesses to an answer. The thread to date is already informative and can stand on its own two feet. In due course someone else might have a much better answer.